# How to add or remove a element in double nested array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, mongodb-nodejs-driver

Example of the document:

```
{
    postId:'232323',
    post:'This is my first post',
    commentsOnPost:[
        {
            commentId:'232323_8888',
            comment:'Congrats',
            repliesOnPost:[
                {
                    replyId:'232323_8888_66666',
                    reply:'Thanks',
                    likesOnReply:['user1','user5','user3'],
                    
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add `userid` in `likesOnReply` if users do not exist in `likesOnReply`, similarly remove `userid` from `likesOnReply` if exist.

I have tried like this but not working properly

```
   await collection('post').findOneAndUpdate(
                {
                    postId: postId,
                    'commentsOnPost.commentId': commentId,
                    'commentsOnPost.repliesOnPost.replyId': replyId
                },
                {

                    $push: { 'commentsOnPost.$[].repliesOnPost.$.likes': userid },
                },

            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight way to do both the operation to pull or push in a single query,

There are 2 approaches,

**1) Find and update using 2 queries:**

- use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to updated nested array elements
- `$push` to insert element
- `$pull` to remove element

```
var post = await collection('post').findOne({
  posted: postId,
  ommentsOnPost: {
    $elemMatch: {
      commentId: commentId,
      repliesOnPost: {
        $elemMatch: {
          replyId: replyId
          likesOnReply: userid
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

var updateOperator = "$push";
// FOUND USER ID THEN DO REMOVE OPERATION
if (post) updateOperator = "$pull";

// QUERY
await collection('post').updateOne(
  { postId: postId },
  {
    [updateOperator]: {
      "commentsOnPost.$[c].repliesOnPost.$[r].likesOnReply": userid
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { "c.commentId": commentId },
      { "r.replyId": replyId }
    ]
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CHmSYl5wN_f)

**2) [Update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2:**

- `$map` to iterate loop of `commentsOnPost` array check condition if `commentId` match then go to next process otherwise return existing object
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object with updated fields
- `$map` to iterate loop of `repliesOnPost` array and check condition if `replyId` match then go to next process otherwise return an existing object
- check condition for `likesOnReply` has `userid` then do remove using `$filter` otherwise insert using `$concatArrays`

```
await collection('post').findOneAndUpdate(
  { postId: "232323" },
  [{
    $set: {
      commentsOnPost: {
        $map: {
          input: "$commentsOnPost",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: ["$$this.commentId", commentId] },
              {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$this",
                  {
                    repliesOnPost: {
                      $map: {
                        input: "$$this.repliesOnPost",
                        in: {
                          $cond: [
                            { $eq: ["$$this.replyId", replyId] },
                            {
                              $mergeObjects: [
                                "$$this",
                                {
                                  likesOnReply: {
                                    $cond: [
                                      { $in: [userid, "$$this.likesOnReply"] },
                                      {
                                        $filter: {
                                          input: "$$this.likesOnReply",
                                          cond: { $ne: ["$$this", userid] }
                                        }
                                      },
                                      {
                                        $concatArrays: ["$$this.likesOnReply", [userid]]
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "$$this"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playgorund](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DpbaUGznl8U)